# How to count documents with mongodb and node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I  want to save the amount of documents of a collection in "const amount_documents". As described in this question: How to get all count of mongoose model? you can not simply write

```
const amount_documents = User.count();
```

What is the correct way to do this? When I use this code:

```
  var myCallback = User.count({}, function(err, count) {
    callback(count);
  });
```

it says "callback is not defined"

Comment: Where do you define `callback`? I suspect your functionis running correctly but just doesnt have a callback reference. Thry this and see:

`var myCallback = User.count({}, function(err, count) {
    console.log(count);
  });`

Answer (score 1):

User.count is asynchronous, with this syntax, you have to execute your code in a callback, this way :

```
  User.count({}, function(err, count) {
    const amount_documents = count;
    // your code using the count
  });
```

If you are using promise and await/async syntax, you can do it like this :

```
const amount_documents = await User.count({});
// Your code using the count here
```